# Wrapping a Firebase Task<Void> into RxJava CompletableEmitter?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to wrap a **Firestore method** into CompletableEmitter, to be able to return Completable.complete() on success/complete, and Completable.error() on failure.
(The Task is a Firestore operation to update a document(1 field in that document) in a collection)

[This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#update(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) is the `firestore method` I am trying to wrap into a [Completable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html) which returns a `Task<Void>`. And here is the code without having it wrapped in a Completable:

```
public static Completable updateDocument(DocumentReference ref, Map<String,Object> fieldsAndValues){
    ref.update(fieldsAndValues)
                .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                    Timber.d("SUCCESS");
                }).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    Timber.d("COMPLETE");
                }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Timber.d("ERROR");
                });
        return Completable.complete();    //just for the sake of returning complete to finish the method...
}
```

This above code executes as is should.

Here is my attempt to wrap that code :

```
public static Completable updateDocument(DocumentReference ref, Map<String,Object> fieldsAndValues){
    return Completable.create(emitter -> ref.update(fieldsAndValues)
       .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> emitter.onComplete())
       .addOnCompleteListener(task -> emitter.onComplete())
       .addOnFailureListener(emitter::onError));
}
```

While the first executes with success (onSuccess called, document in Firestore updated), the wrapped code never reaches onSuccess from the Task (onSuccess never reached, document never updated in Firestore). But it does not throw any errors, The Task completes but never reaches success.

I do not understand this behavior. Any suggestions? What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to use the callbacks for a task - I think that the api is restrictive in this sense.

you can make the task blocking and just evaluate it after execution i.e.

```
public static Completable updateDocument(DocumentReference ref, Map<String,Object> fieldsAndValues){
        return Completable.fromCallable(() -> {
            final Task<Void> task = ref.update(fieldsAndValues);
            Tasks.await(task);
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                return Completable.complete();
            } else {
                return Completable.error(new IllegalStateException("Task not successful", task.getException()));
            }
        });
    }
```

As your original problem, try holding a reference to the task in the closure i.e.

```
public static Completable updateDocument(DocumentReference ref, Map<String, Object> fieldsAndValues) {
        return Completable.create(emitter -> {
            final Task<Void> task = ref.update(fieldsAndValues)
            task.addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> emitter.onComplete())
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> emitter.onComplete())
                    .addOnFailureListener(emitter::onError);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. The second part is correct (and make more sense for my situation). But how come? Could you explain please, if you have time?

Comment: Glad your problem is solved.  As the closure does not hold a reference to the `Task` object returned it is up for garbage collection once it falls out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Have you `subscribe`d returned completable?
`ref.update()` will be never executed unless you subscribe it

```
updateDocument(...)
    .subscribe(...) // <- this
```

Note: There is also wrong with your first code.
`Completable`s should be executed when they are `subscribe`d. However in your first code, it is executed when you call `updateDocument()`.
For example, if you do `Completable c = updateDocument(...)`, it should not update document because you did not `subscribe()` yet but your first code it will update document.

Comment: Yes, I do subscribe. From another class I do: disposable = FirebaseClass.updatedocument(ref,map).subscribeOn(...).observeOn(..).subscribe(this::onSuccess,this::onError) etc

Comment: hmm... please log with `doOnSubscribe` or debugger to stop with ref.update, to check it actually subscribes. If you are actually subscribing and it doesn't work, it's suspicious. It looks Firestore is working asynchronously by default so Rx threading might be troubling with it.

Comment: I did a lot of debugging/logging, and as you said, it's suspicious looking. As it turns out, I was complete missing the problem, It was not a Firebase nor a RxJava problem. Look at @MarkKeen answer, the second part. I had to hold a reference to my task outside the Completable. Anyways, Thanks for your reply I appreciate the help, I did upvote. Thanks.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that! That's interesting point. I've completely forgot if it might be reference problem :P